# Как использовать разметку HTML

Tags: javascript, html, yii2, vue.js, rest

возник такой вопрос.
Делаю рест приложение на стеке Yii2+Vue.js
При выводе текста на сайте (через Vue.js) хочу чтобы HTML тэги в тексте работали, а не были частью текста.
Сейчас при сохранении текста в админке:

```
<b>Контакты</b>
```

На сайте выведется так целиком "`<b>Контакты</b>`".
Соотвественно как сделать, чтобы тэг применился к слову контакты? И слово стало с жирным шрифтом. И на какой стороне должна проходить данная операция?

Comment: а зачем вообще теги  можно же так  <b>{{ contacts }}</b>

Comment: Нужно, чтобы текст можно было форматировать с помощью html, контакты это просто пример. На деле там большой текст которые добавляется через админку и в нем нужно допустим выделять отдельные слова.

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html  вот ту думаю вам поможет  а именно v-html

Comment: Да, то что нужно. Спасибо!